# Replace method generates application-defined or object-defined error in Excel for Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2011

I'm having trouble with this on the latest version of Excel for Mac.

Here's the macro:

```
Sub Run()
'
' Run Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("BK1").Activate
    Selection.Replace What:="unknown", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Sheets("Pivot Table").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotCache.Refresh
    Sheets("Formatted Data").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatted Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatted Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key _
        :=Range("A4"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatted Data").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With



End Sub
```

When I run it, I get a MSFT Visual Basic error:

```
 Run-time error '1004':

 Application-defined or object-defined error
```

If I remove this part, it runs fine, but isn't exactly what I need in terms of final result:

```
Sheets("Data").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("BK1").Activate
    Selection.Replace What:="unknown", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

**UPDATE**

If I remove just this little part, the macro runs, but not sure if I lose anything by removing this:

```
SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Narrowing it down further will help.  Add those commands back one at a time until you determine exactly which of those four is causing the error.  Does your Selection actually contain what you expect before you run the Replace?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Good idea. I tried this and found I only needed to remove a small bit (see updated answer), but I'm not sure how this will affect my results. I'm working with someone else's macro here, so I don't know fully how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh, found some reference ([in a comment on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039440/vba-find-method-errors-on-excel-mac-2011), and in the [MS forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/excel-2007-to-excel-mac-2011-vba-conversion-help/2cdd4e37-636f-4cf7-a13d-aa8575d1f7ae?auth=1)) that the SearchFormat option isn't valid in the Mac version of Excel.

Others may not be as well, but I can't find any documentation on the OSX version of Office VBA, so I can't really confirm it directly from MS.